# Nvidia and yamaha HTR-2067 and windows 10 "works" negative (DVI->HDMI)

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, dvi

I bought yamaha HTR-2067. It works almost perfectly, but for some reason it doesn't play sound from PC (HP Elitebook 8560w).

The strangest is, that if I turn yamaha OFF, on Sound Devices appears NVIDIA High Definition Audio, and even green bar jumps with music, I can even set up 5.1 speakers etc. But of course I can't hear the music, because yamaha is off.

If I turn yamaha ON, the device changes status to not plugged in... And of course I can't hear the music, because WIndows doesn't want to play to disconnected device.

**update**
I forgot to write, that connection is DVI->HDMI. And the video signal works normal - if yamaha is on, I can see computer on HDMI output, if off - of course can't see ;D

Any ideas???

Comment: How do you have the receiver connected to the HP?  What type of cable?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot write that I use DVI->HDMI cable

Comment: **DVI does not carry sound**, so you are losing the signal, hence the reason you have no sound

Comment: This is not true: "The audio can be carried over DVI to HDMI cable depending on the graphics card. For newer GPUs, you just need to set the HDMI audio device in the Windows Sound control panel. Older GPUs need to use a digital audio S/PDIF cable to connect from the PC to the graphics board's on board S/PDIF connector. Please contact your graphics board manufacturer if you have questions on supporting HDMI audio over DVI." http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2562/~/if-i-am-using-a-dvi-to-hdmi-cable-will-audio-be-transmitted-over-this-cable-to

Comment: That article does not apply to the author's usage

Comment: @Ramhound Why? 1. Audio CAN be carried over DVI to HDMI (my case), 2. depending on the graphics card (my card support HDMI Audio - i see device in sound devices) 3. WIndows even correctly detects amplituner over DVI. ONLY incorrectly detect if it on or OFF